# Show 10kers some simple analytics in the tools

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, 10k-tools, analytics

Currently, only Diamond mods have access to *real* analytics - with pretty graphs and stuff. I'm currently helping in a Beta site, and I'm very interested in how the site is doing. Because of this, I have a big system set up that collects stats from the API on a regular interval. This works *ok*, but... it's not optimal.

[image]

<sup>If I can make this with the API, why can't we show it to 10kers?</sup>

*Some* analytics [are even available publicly](https://www.quantcast.com/space.stackexchange.com).

Why can't we show 10kers at least a normalized graph of visits? We don't need crazy-detailed graphs, a rolling average is fine. If needed, we could even make this a 20k (or greater?) privilege.

What's standing in the way of doing this? Why don't we want high privileged users having analytics?

Comment: From what I've seen the publicly available stats are not too bad, reasonably in the same ballpark. We have [a Meta post](http://meta.martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/316/keeping-track-of-our-statistics) which one of our users is doing a great job of keeping updated with the latest Quantcast figures - could your site not do the same?

Comment: I have plans to, actually. It just seems like something that 10kers should have access to *anyway*.

Comment: Is there a reason it should be gated behind a rather high reputation barrier, if the information is available in the API in the first place?

Comment: @3ventic It's only available through the API if *you* track it over time - keeping your own historical database.

Comment: How many 20k users are you going to have on a beta site that aren't also already pro-tem mods?

Comment: @Troyen The priv levels would be different on beta sites, of course - and it's just a suggestion. The core of this is *get stats in front of normal users*.

Comment: I agree on showing to normal users, especially since [people have a tendency to graph the public Area 51 stats anyway](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/437/fun-with-numbers-jlu-usage-graphs).  It just seems like restricting to Trusted 20K (4K) users adds maybe a handful of people.  Using Japanese as an example, there would be 24 people that would gain access to these stats, half aren't active anymore, 2 are mods, and maybe a few of the remainder actually participate on meta/chat.  In contrast, 4K still locks out most of the meta/chat community that would care about this.